# Export more than one DB Table as SQL Data

Tags: php, xml

I'm looking to export 11 Database tables' data as XML. I've easily managed to export one table, without issue. But I am looking to export more than one really.

I'm sure theres a way and obviously output the data as seperate table entitys. Any help is much appreciated on this one, As I'm finding it a little tricky.

My code is as follows

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$database   = "db_etch";
$table = "keywords";

$SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM $table";

$DB_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $DB_link) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");
$result = mysql_query ($SQL_query, $DB_link) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL query didn't work... ");

// produce XML
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";

// root node
$XML .= "<result>\n";
// rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
  $XML .= "\t<$table>\n"; 
  $i = 0;
  // cells
  foreach ($row as $cell) {

    $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);
    $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
    $XML .= "\t\t<" . $col_name . ">" . $cell . "</" . $col_name . ">\n";
    $i++;
  }
  $XML .= "\t</$table>\n"; 
 }
$XML .= "</result>\n";

// output the whole XML string
echo $XML;

// Write $sql to file   
$File = "keywords.xml";
$fh = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $XML;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed some of your code, assuming some little extra what you wanted:

- Changed str_replace() to htmlspecialchars()
- Moved xml start to the beginning.
- Added a new root node.

That's about it. If you want to output all tables from a certain db, you should use "show tables;" -query to find out the tables that the db consist of.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$database   = "db_etch";
$table = "keywords";

$tables_to_output_array = array('keywords', 'othertable1', 'othertable2');


$DB_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");

mysql_select_db($database, $DB_link) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");

// produce XML
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
// root node
$XML .= "<tables>\n";

while (list(, $table) = each($tables_to_output_array)) {


  $SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM $table";

  $result = mysql_query ($SQL_query, $DB_link) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL query didn't work... ");

  // tables
  $XML .= "\t<$table>\n";
  // rows
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $XML .= "\t\t<row>\n"; 
    $i = 0;
    // cells
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
      $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
      $XML .= "\t\t\t<" . $col_name . ">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</" . $col_name . ">\n";
      $i++;
    }
    $XML .= "\t\t</row>\n"; 
   }
  $XML .= "\t</$table>\n";

}

$XML .= "</tables>\n";

// output the whole XML string
echo $XML;

// Write $sql to file   
$File = "keywords.xml";
$fh = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $XML;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Was just looking at for and while loops on an array then came across your answer, Much appreciated!!